# Structuring dependencies in Angular JS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering how the best way to go about this is.  I have a controller that has two extra parameters injected: `ConfigService` and `DataAccess`. ConfigService returns a configuration object for a directive.  The config objects are stored in a JS variable inside the service.  The "data" property of ConfigService return object is fetched using `DataAccess`.

So my controller depends on `ConfigService`'s return object to provide it some config data.  That config service depends on DataAccess.

Is it correct to have my controller depend on both, or should I have my ConfigService depend on DataAccess, and then have my controller depend only on ConfigService?

Comment: i don't think config should depend on anything, except maybe some other config. DataAccess would probably depend on config. but yes you should declare both, unless you are planning on delivering one through the other which would defeat the purpose of then being separated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The Code Reviewers Guide (http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) written by Misko way before he started working on AngularJS actually has some great tips on this very thing.

What you are mentioning could fall under Flaw #2, digging into collaborators. The simple rule of thumb is if you need to access variables or keys from ConfigService in your controller, you should inject ConfigService into your controller. You should not access it via the DataAccess service. On the other hand, if there is nothing you need directly from the ConfigService, then do not inject it in.

The reverse is true as well - If your controller truly has no need for DataAccess (as you make it out to be), then there is no need to inject DataAccess into your controller. Let ConfigService deal with it, and let the controller deal with the fully loaded ConfigService.